# How to change the background color of current day in jquery datepicker onclick?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using jQuery datepicker in angularjs,
By overriding css I am displaying orange color background to the current date

```
.ui-state-highlight{
    background-color:orange;
}
```

Now the requirement is the background color of current date must be changed to red when clicked.
I have tried calling a function onSelect which changes the background color in datepicker defaults,but that's not working.How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You could use onSelect event to change the css of current date

```
onSelect: function(value, date) {
    date.dpDiv.find('.ui-datepicker-current-day')
        .addClass('ui-state-highlight');
}
```

I would recommend against using mechanism above, instead you could override `.ui-datepicker-current-day` class like this

```
.ui-datepicker-current-day{
    background-color:orange;
}
```

that will not require JS.