# Change the color on selected JQuery UI datepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui-datepicker

i am trying to use jqueryui datepicker.I want to use the inline mode. I get the selected date when user selects a date. What I want to know is visually change the background color of the selected date. I only have a hover, but I would need a "selected" background color change:

https://jsfiddle.net/vum5816p/9/

```
    var sale = [];

    $('#datepickerdiv').datepicker({
      onSelect: function(dateText, instance) {
        sale.push('fecha: "' + dateText + '"');
      }       
    });`
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a jQueryUI [theme](https://jqueryui.com/themeroller/), or by finding out the right CSS selector using your browser's inspect element tool.

Comment: That won't tell me the javascript code to make the color stick. I dont think you understood what I want to do, I want the selected date, to change background color and 'hold it' until a new selection is made. I would have to wonder about two things:
- the 'click out' event to apply the background color and have it stick
- the 'removal' of previous selected date, if any

Comment: jQuery UI uses CSS to achieve the styling for the selected state. There might be javascript code that you can do but it is redundant, use CSS to tweak the selected CSS class that gets automatically applied by jquery UI upon date selection.

Comment: Not sure css by itself, can add the behavior to either, check other dates are not previously selected, nor trigger the background dinamically on an event. Which is what I am asking here.
What I want is similar to this question, except I am not looking for current date but 'current-selection'. Which I dont believe there is a classs for it.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24449323/how-to-change-the-background-color-of-current-day-in-jquery-datepicker-onclick?rq=1

Comment: Are you certain your use case isn't the default behaviour as outlined on https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/ because every description you have said is what I know to be in the default behaviour, you are just missing CSS. Date picker allows only one date to be selected by default, and the default behaviour adds a selected day class to the right table cell when selected.